# Помогите разобраться с ресурсами Maven в файле jar

Tags: java, maven, io

В общем проблема такая. Я уже прочитал про осуществление доступа к ресурсам при помощи конструкции getClass().getResource(). В моем случае это не помогает от слова совсем. В папке resources есть директория Files, в которой лежит несколько текстовых документов. Основная задача процедуры - просмотреть эту директорию, вернуть из нее массив файлов с помощью метода .listFiles() и в последствии все это дело заворачивается в список классов-оберток над File. В коде все это дело выглядит так:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("Files").getFile());
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        else {
            File[] arrFiles = file.listFiles();
            if (arrFiles!=null){
                for (File k:arrFiles){
                    FilePacket ks = new FilePacket(k);
                    if(!clientFiles.contains(ks)){
                        clientFiles.add(ks);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
```

Когда проект собирается, папка Files вместе с файлами помещается в корень jar. Так вот как в моем случае написать пути или поступить так, чтобы в jar файлы также сканировались и находились?

Answer (score 0):

1. Использовать абсолютный путь - "/Files" 
   или
2. Создать в каталоге resources пакет, в котором лежит класс и положить туда Files. Напр.: класс лежит в пакете some.package.name => такой же пакет создаём в resources и туда кладем Files: resources/some/package/name/Files/ 
   или
3. Использовать getClassLoader() вместо getClass()

Comment: getClassLoader проблему не решает к сожалению, а путь файлов выглядит вот так LZ78Coder_Decoder-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/Files, ну и естественно через джарник пробиться нельзя в таком пути

Comment: Что конкретно вам нужно от файлов, их содержимое или метаинфа?

Comment: Мне нужно прописать пути таким образом, чтобы вышенаписанная конструкция смогла отработать внутри jar, чтобы нашлась сама директория в корневой папке, и нашлись все текстовые документы, которые будут лежать в ней на момент скана

Comment: В таком случае рассмотрите использование [ZipFileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)